# Exception Handling C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, exception, windows-forms-designer

I am relatively new at this and have been racking my brain attempting to get my program to work properly and it just won't. I am working in Visual Studio 2012 C# on a Forms Application.

I need it to produce a distinct error message when the user input value is more than `0` but less than `10,000`. It also must produce a distinct error message when the user enters a non-numeric value and a distinct error message when the user fails to enter any value at all.

The code I've written so far produces a distinct error message when the user enters a non-numeric value or when they fail to enter any value at all, but it does not trigger an error message when the user enters a value that is below or over the required range.

It is as if the compiler is ignoring the code I've written for the first exception/overflow exception and only recognizing the code for the second and final exception. My code has no coding errors. It appears that my problem is in the logic.

Please help me if you can. My code is below thanks!

```
    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            {

                decimal subtotal = Convert.ToDecimal(txtSubtotal.Text);
                decimal discountPercent = .25m;
                decimal discountAmount = subtotal * discountPercent;
                decimal invoiceTotal = subtotal - discountAmount;

                lblDiscountPercent.Text = discountPercent.ToString("p1");
                lblDiscountAmount.Text = discountAmount.ToString("c");
                lblTotal.Text = invoiceTotal.ToString("c");

            }
        }
        catch (OverflowException)

        {
            decimal subtotal = Convert.ToDecimal(txtSubtotal.Text);

            if (subtotal <= 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Subtotal must be greater than $0.00. ", "Error Entry");
                txtSubtotal.Focus();
            }

             if (subtotal >= 10000)

            {
                MessageBox.Show("Subtotal must be less than $10000.00. ", "Error Entry");
                txtSubtotal.Focus();
            }
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {

            if (txtSubtotal.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Subtotal is a required field. ", "Error Entry");
            }


            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(
                 "Please enter a valid Number for the subtotal field.", "Error Entry");
                txtSubtotal.Focus();
            }


            }           

        }




    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void txtSubtotal_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Move your code out of the exception block, make it the first thing you do when they click the button or whatever

Comment: Post all of your code (specifically the code in your try block). An overflow exception will not be thrown (by default at least) if an input is outside of 0 and 10,000.

Comment: Why should it be part of exception?You could simply write a validation class where you should either return true or false before performing any action.Your program will never come to catch block if your code is syntactically correct and does not break on run time.

Comment: set breakpoints (F9) to check which part of you code is actually executed. Obviously nothing from the posted lines

Comment: I'm trying to post the rest of the try block but there is a character restriction in the comment section

Comment: private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                {

                    decimal subtotal = Convert.ToDecimal(txtSubtotal.Text);
                    decimal discountPercent = .25m;
                    decimal discountAmount = subtotal * discountPercent;
                    decimal invoiceTotal = subtotal - discountAmount;

Comment: lblDiscountPercent.Text = discountPercent.ToString("p1");
                    lblDiscountAmount.Text = discountAmount.ToString("c");
                    lblTotal.Text = invoiceTotal.ToString("c");

                }
            }

Comment: That is the rest of my try block

Comment: Please edit code in original question.not in comment

Comment: okay sorry, I'm really new to this. I just figured out how to edit. It's updated now.

Comment: Okay I have finally gotten it together guys. Again my apologies.

Comment: Thank you guys! It worked!!!  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I already mentioned in comment you should consider moving your code out of catch block.

In this case you should think of creating a simple method which will validate your input and produces output message.

An example is for you:

```
  private bool IsPageValid()  
  {
           string errorMessage = string.Empty;               
           bool isValid = true;
           if (subtotal <= 0)
           {
           errorMessage+="<li>"+"<b>Subtotal must be greater than $0.00. ", "Error Entry"+ "</b><br/>";
           txtSubtotal.Focus();
           isValid=false;
           }
   }
```

> ***Likewise write other clause of validations in this function.***.This will validate each of your condition and if fails it would make the isValid false thus not allowing users to submit.

Now you should call this function in your button click.

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            ClearMessage();
            if (IsPageValid().Equals(true))
            {
             // allow next action to happen.
            }
     }
```

Comment: Furthermore if he wishes to have a red border on an invalid value he can call IsPageValid() in the TextChanged callback of his TextBox, I prefer that in an application.

Answer (score 2):

I would used KeyEvent press enter or Leave event for this, first I need to create generic class for verification if the input from the user is not a string.
Condition:
1 verify if the input is not a string Im using generic for general purposes class.

```
   public class iCnF()
   {
    public static System.Boolean IsNumeric(System.Object Expression) 
      {
        if (Expression == null || Expression is DateTime)
            return false;
        if (Expression is Int16 || Expression is Int32 || Expression is Int64 || Expression is Decimal || Expression is Single || Expression is Double || Expression is Boolean)
            return true;
        try 
        {
            if(Expression is string)
                Double.Parse(Expression as string);
            else
                Double.Parse(Expression.ToString());
                return true;
        } catch {} // just dismiss errors but return false
            return false;
     }
}
```

2. Then I need to verify if the input is not empty

   ```
      private void txtSubtotal_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
      {
       if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter || e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
       {
           if (txtSubtotal.Text.Length > 0)
           {
               bool sd = iCnF.IsNumeric(txtSubtotal.Text);
               if (sd == false)
               {
                  MessageBox.Show("Subtotal must be a numeric value. ", "Error Entry");

                  txtSubtotal.Clear();
                  txtSubtotal.Focus();
               }
               else
               {
                   decimal subtotal = Convert.ToDecimal(txtSubtotal.Text);
                   if (subtotal <= 0)
                   {
                       MessageBox.Show("Subtotal must be greater than $0.00. ", "Error Entry");
                       txtSubtotal.Focus();
                  }

                  if (subtotal >= 10000)
                  {
                      MessageBox.Show("Subtotal must be less than $10000.00. ", "Error Entry");
                      txtSubtotal.Focus();
                  }
              }
          }
          else
          {
              MessageBox.Show("Subtotal must not be empty. ", "Error Entry");
              txtSubtotal.Focus();
          }
      }
     }
   ```
3. if not empty and numberic value my subtotal <= 0 and subtotal >= 10000

Hope this will help you :D

Comment: Thank you so much. I am working these assignments out of Murach Training Manual and trying to get a good feel for programming in the real world. You gave me some great tips and I appreciate that.

Comment: user3473475 no problem please mark it check my answer for reference, for someone who have the same problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Code should look like this

```
try {
    decimal subtotal = Convert.ToDecimal(txtSubtotal.Text);
    try {
        if(x<0 || x>10000){
            throw new OverFlowException("");
        }
        //Do what ever you want
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        // catch overflow
    }
}
catch(Exception ex){
    // catch nonnumeric value
}
```